# Belkin mobile wireless keyboard F5L175 set to wrong language on galaxy tab e, how to fix

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, external-keyboard

After pairing my galaxy tab e to Belkin mobile wireless keyboard, everything worked fine. The second time I connected a screen came up asking me to set language. Apparently I picked incorrect English US option because it now types some letters different than keyboard. How can this be fixed?  Can't find any reference to a setting anywhere on tablet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here’s how to set things right. First, turn on bluetooth on your device & connect to the external keyboard. On android device, you need to go into the Settings menu, then find the ‘Language & input’ option. (On recent versions of Android, you should see a ‘Select keyboard layout’ option in your notifications, which will take you to the same place.)

From here, find your Bluetooth keyboard listed under ‘Physical keyboard’ and press on its name. A menu will appear that lets you choose a keyboard language. If you don’t see the correct option, choose ‘Set up keyboard language’. Then, find your desired language (e.g. English – US android) and tick the box. Now your Bluetooth keyboard should be set to its desired language.
Thanks to the guys at MobileFun.uk